# ClassNotFoundException when trying to deploy a DataSource with @DataSourceDefinition

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy a datasource with the @DataSourceDefinition-Annotation.

When wildfly deploys the jar, it throws a ClassNotFoundException.

I put the mysql-jdbc-Driver in the deployment-directory. I already use the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class in Datasources configured in standalone.xml. I havn't created a module with the jdbc-driver under "modules\system\layers\base"

Here is the Class with the Annotation:

```
@Stateless
@DataSourceDefinition(name = "java:global/jdbc/testingDS",
    className = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    portNumber = 3306,
    serverName = "localhost",
    databaseName = "testing",
    user = "testing",
    password = "testing")

public class DataSourceDeployment {
  public void someMethod() { }
}
```

And here is the Exception (this is the *.failed-File):

```
{
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.jar\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module \"deployment.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module \"deployment.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment.ORB is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.jar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.jar\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment.HandleDelegate is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment]",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DatasourceDeploymentTest-1.DataSourceDeployment]"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CFNE is just as it should be.

You have mysql jdbc driver in module but your deployment and it's `@DataSourceDefinition` know noting about it.

`@DataSourceDefinition` uses deployments classloader to load the jdbc driver but it is not available to it as it is in module.

To solve this you should either

1) add deployment's  dependency to your mysql driver module via manifest.mf / jboss-deployment-structure.xml, see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly for details how

2) add jdbc driver to your war's lib directory

but I would definitely go with 1)